# Аутентификация приложения с Laravel

Tags: php, android, laravel

Я пишу Restful, используя 'Laravel'. Делаю это всё впервые и пока не особо понимаю, что да как.
У меня есть приложение (Андроид), и мне нужно что-бы мой restful мог получать запросы только от этого приложения. Для этого, как я понимаю, надо как-то аутентифицировать моё приложение, но как это сделать, я не понимаю.
Я ещё новичок в программировании, поэтому простите, если мой вопрос оказался глупым.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начиная с 5.2 стандартно поддерживается возможность задать каждому пользователю уникальный api key:

> Jacob Bennett has written a fantastic post on that already: [API Token Authentication in Laravel 5.2.](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/multiple-authentication-guard-drivers-including-api-in-laravel-5-2)
>
> Check out his post to learn more about how it works, but here's the
>   short of it:

- Add an api_token column to your users table. 60-character string,
  unique. Instead of using the auth middleware in your route
  definition, use the auth:api middleware.
- In your API routes, use
  Auth::guard('api')->user() to get your user instead of Auth::user().
  As you can see, we need to store an api_token for each user, and
  every incoming request that's guarded by the token-driven api guard
  will require a query parameter named api_token with a valid API token
  set to authenticate that user. And since it's stateless, every
  request will need to have this API token set; one successful request
  won't affect the next request.

Для добавления на стороне Android например через Retrofit попробуйте явно указать @Query или так [Retrofit 2 — How to Add Query Parameters to Every Request](https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-2-how-to-add-query-parameters-to-every-request)

Answer (score 2):

Добрый день. Я бы рекомендовал вам использование JWT token.
http://jwt.io/

Для того что бы сказать вашему приложения что вы авторизованный пользователь.

Мы шлем в HEADERS: {X-AUTH-TOKEN: JWT}
GET /user/{id}/friends

Для того что бы получить token

POST /token
{username: "", password: ""}

Готовый проект который вам поможет разобраться
https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth

Удачной разработки!